# How read csv file only specific columns using javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, csv

I have created a function for csv reader using react-file-reader. It´s working fine and data is successfully uploaded into the database but that csv file have more than 10 columns. I want only the first three and fifth column.

That´s my code

```
const reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsText(files[0]);
reader.onload = (x) => {
  console.log('check data 1 :', x);
  console.log('check data :', x.currentTarget.result.split('/n'));

  const lines = x.currentTarget.result.split('\n');

  const result = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < lines.length - 1; i++) {
    const obj = {};
    //const newObj = lines.splice(4,1);
    const currentline = lines[i].split(',');
    const headers = ['ac_no', 'name', 'date_time', 'check_type'];
    for (let j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {

          obj[headers[j]] = currentline[j];

    }

    result.push(obj);

  }
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a *column index* array where to set which columns to pick, e.g.

```
const headers = ['ac_no', 'name', 'date_time', 'check_type'];
const columns = [0, 1, 2, 4];
for (let j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {

      obj[headers[j]] = currentline[columns[j]];

}
```